# What does 'Bd' stand for in device test standard context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, abbreviations

> The equipment shall be subjected to the dry test specified in EN 60068-2-2 Test **Bd** for the limits corresponding to the class of operation claimed by the supplier and specified in clause 11.

That's a quote from a certification document, citing a standard's requirements. What does the 'Bd' abbreviation mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Bd* is not the object of the verb *test* here: it's the name/designation of a test. The equipment shall be tested using the test called "EN 60068-2-2 Test Bd".

I would surmise that there are a number of tests, labelled at least A to N, and test B has a number of variants, Ba, Bb, Bc and Bd.

From the [IEC version of the standard](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/510) (with my emphasis):

> IEC 60068-2-2:2007 Deals with dry heat tests applicable both to heat-dissipating and non heat-dissipating specimens. For non heat-dissipating specimens, **Tests Bb and Bd** do not deviate essentially from earlier issues. The object of the dry heat test is limited to the determination of the ability of components, equipment or other articles to be used, transported or stored at high temperature. These dry heat tests do not enable the ability of specimens to withstand or operate during the temperature variations to be assessed. In this case, it would be necessary to use IEC 60068-2-14 Test N: Change of temperature.
>
> The dry heat tests are subdivided as follows:
>
> - Dry heat test for non heat-dissipating specimens with gradual change of temperature, Bb.
> - Dry heat tests for heat-dissipating specimens with gradual change of temperature, **Bd;**

Answer (score 1):

https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/510

I looks like the identifier of the type of test to be conducted.  There is a test matrix in the standard (EN 60068-2-2).  The upper case letter is the column and the row is the lower case letter.